# split the column with list into multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know there have been many questions on this topic, but still:
My input: as dataframe

```
 task                                            m_label
0  S101-10061  [Cecum Landmark, ICV, Comment, Appendiceal ori...
1  S101-10069  [Rectum RF, ICV, Cecum Landmark, TI, Comment, ...
2  S101-10078  [Appendiceal orifice, ICV, Cecum Landmark, Com...
3  S101-10088  [Cecum Landmark, ICV, Comment, Appendiceal ori...
4  S101-10100  [Transverse, Appendiceal orifice, ICV, Cecum L...
5  S101-10102  [Rectum RF, ICV, Cecum Landmark, Comment, TI, ...
6  S101-10133  [Rectum RF, Transverse, ICV, Cecum Landmark, C...
7  S101YGBgZ2                                          [Comment]
```

I wan to split like `df.m_label.str.split("",expand=True)` but it return `NaN`
Maybe problem with df? I get its from panda Series from: `m_lab_task=data.groupby(['task'])['m_label'].unique()`. So maybe in previously step it possible correct?

Required output:

```
      task       m_label1 m_label2 m_label3 m_label4 m_label5 m_label6
0   S101-10061  Cecum Landmark ICV Comment Appendiceal orifice
1   S101-10069  Rectum RF ICV Cecum Landmark TI Comment Transverse
2   S101-10078  Appendiceal orifice ICV Cecum Landmark Comment Transverse
 Rectum RF
```

Comment: Why some values are enclosed inside double quotes `"` and some not? Is `m_lbel` a string column or does it have python lists?

Comment: Sorry for confusing

Comment: Do you want the values inside single quotes `''` to be in a separate column?

Comment: Yes, I wan split object, which was created by function pandas.groupby() in column m_label to separate "labels"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you convert the list into dataframe string data without separation will combine as single data to overcome this you have insert the comma before convert into dataframe like this,

```
import pandas as pd
data={"task":["S101-10061","S101-10069","S101-10078","S101-10088","S101-10100","S101-10102","S101-10133","S101YGBgZ2"],
     "m_label":[['Cecum Landmark','ICV' ,'Comment' ,'Appendiceal orifice'],['Rectum RF','ICV','Cecum Landmark','TI','Comment','Transverse']
               ,['Appendiceal orifice' ,'ICV' ,'Cecum Landmark', 'Comment', 'Transverse','Rectum RF'],['Cecum Landmark', 'ICV', 'Comment', 'Appendiceal orifice'],
               ['Transverse' ,'Appendiceal orifice', 'ICV', 'Cecum Landmark', 'Comment'],['Rectum RF' ,'ICV' ,'Cecum Landmark', 'Comment' ,'TI' ,'Transverse','Appendiceal orifice'],
               ['Rectum RF', 'Transverse' ,'ICV' ,'Cecum Landmark', 'Comment'],['Comment']]}
data=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

dataframe should like this

```
        task    m_label
0   S101-10061  [Cecum Landmark, ICV, Comment, Appendiceal ori...
1   S101-10069  [Rectum RF, ICV, Cecum Landmark, TI, Comment, ...
2   S101-10078  [Appendiceal orifice, ICV, Cecum Landmark, Com...
3   S101-10088  [Cecum Landmark, ICV, Comment, Appendiceal ori...
4   S101-10100  [Transverse, Appendiceal orifice, ICV, Cecum L...
5   S101-10102  [Rectum RF, ICV, Cecum Landmark, Comment, TI, ...
6   S101-10133  [Rectum RF, Transverse, ICV, Cecum Landmark, C...
7   S101YGBgZ2  [Comment]
```

output code

```
import numpy as np
data=pd.concat([data["task"],data["m_label"].apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x).add_prefix("m_label"))],axis=1).replace(np.nan," ")

task    m_label0    m_label1    m_label2    m_label3    m_label4    m_label5    m_label6
0   S101-10061  Cecum Landmark  ICV Comment Appendiceal orifice         
1   S101-10069  Rectum RF   ICV Cecum Landmark  TI  Comment Transverse  
2   S101-10078  Appendiceal orifice ICV Cecum Landmark  Comment Transverse  Rectum RF   
3   S101-10088  Cecum Landmark  ICV Comment Appendiceal orifice         
4   S101-10100  Transverse  Appendiceal orifice ICV Cecum Landmark  Comment     
5   S101-10102  Rectum RF   ICV Cecum Landmark  Comment TI  Transverse  Appendiceal orifice
6   S101-10133  Rectum RF   Transverse  ICV Cecum Landmark  Comment     
7   S101YGBgZ2  Comment
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.findall` and pass the regex to capture everything enclosed by single quite `''`, then apply `pd.Series` to convert them to columns

```py
df=df.set_index('task')['m_label'].str.findall('\'(.*?)\'').apply(pd.Series)
df.columns = [f'm_label{i+1}' for i in df]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
                       m_label1             m_label2        m_label3               m_label4    m_label5    m_label6             m_label7  
task                                                                                                                                       
S101-10061       Cecum Landmark                  ICV         Comment    Appendiceal orifice         NaN         NaN                  NaN   
S101-10069            Rectum RF                  ICV  Cecum Landmark                     TI     Comment  Transverse                  NaN   
S101-10078  Appendiceal orifice                  ICV  Cecum Landmark                Comment  Transverse   Rectum RF                  NaN   
S101-10088       Cecum Landmark                  ICV         Comment    Appendiceal orifice         NaN         NaN                  NaN   
S101-10100           Transverse  Appendiceal orifice             ICV         Cecum Landmark     Comment         NaN                  NaN   
S101-10102            Rectum RF                  ICV  Cecum Landmark                Comment          TI  Transverse  Appendiceal orifice   
S101-10133            Rectum RF           Transverse             ICV         Cecum Landmark     Comment         NaN                  NaN   
S101YGBgZ2              Comment                  NaN             NaN                    NaN         NaN         NaN                  NaN
```

If needed, you can reset the index later, and `fillna('')`.

Comment: I don't understand why for me its return Nan? Maybe something in preference?

Comment: Now, you have updated the question which looks like python list. Try `df[m_label'].apply(type)`  if it's list, then you don't need to use `split`/`findall`, just use `df.set_index('task').apply(pd.Series)`

Comment: task
S101-10061    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Name: m_label, dtype: object

Comment: You have numpy array, just skip `findall` part, it should work fine i.e. `df.set_index('task').apply(pd.Series)`, `findall` is for string type column only, but you have a numpy array.

Comment: Command just return me: same df within 'task' as index and 'm_label' as column in all stuff. Whats wrong? I folow step by step.  Is it problem in previously steps? I use to get pandas series and convert it to df this commands: df=data.groupby(['task'])['m_label'].unique() and df=pd.DataFrame(mltask) df=mltask.reset_index()

Comment: You need to assign it back. `df=df.set_index('task').apply(pd.Series)`, then `print(df)`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something to ThePyGuy's answer,if you want to rename columns "on the fly", you can use `add_prefix()`.

```
df.set_index('task')['m_label'].str.findall('\'(.*?)\'').apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('m_label')
```

output:

```
Out[27]: 
                  m_label0 m_label1  ... m_label4    m_label5
task                                 ...                     
S101-10061  Cecum Landmark      ICV  ...      NaN         NaN
S101-10069       Rectum RF      ICV  ...  Comment  Transverse
```

Answer (score 0):

From Mr.Brarath Narayan code, I hope you can short the code as follows without use of numpy

```
df = pd.concat([df['task'],df['m_label'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("m_label").fillna("")], axis = 1)
```

**Output**

```
task    m_label0    m_label1    m_label2    m_label3    m_label4    m_label5    m_label6
0   S101-10061  Cecum Landmark  ICV Comment Appendiceal orifice         
1   S101-10069  Rectum RF   ICV Cecum Landmark  TI  Comment Transverse  
2   S101-10078  Appendiceal orifice ICV Cecum Landmark  Comment Transverse  Rectum RF   
3   S101-10088  Cecum Landmark  ICV Comment Appendiceal orifice         
4   S101-10100  Transverse  Appendiceal orifice ICV Cecum Landmark  Comment     
5   S101-10102  Rectum RF   ICV Cecum Landmark  Comment TI  Transverse  Appendiceal orifice
6   S101-10133  Rectum RF   Transverse  ICV Cecum Landmark  Comment     
7   S101YGBgZ2  Comment
```